# c++ overload pointer ostream

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, overloading

I am a learning c++ and have a class project due in 5 days.  I've spent 4 hours researching how to do this however I have not come up with an answer yet.  Save me stack!

Problem.  I have a pointer to a class which holds a dynamic array.  I need to take that array and save it to a file to retrieve later.  Here are my 2 headers and the implementation.  I am not writing the code to "save to file" yet as that will be easy once I get around this issue.  My problem is it keeps printing the address of the pointer and not the data within.

**vehReg.h**

```
class vehReg {
    public:
        /* STUFF */
    };
}
#endif
```

**vehData.h**

```
#include "vehReg.h"

using namespace std;

class vehData {
    public:
        //CONSTRUCTORS
        vehData();

        //DECONSTRUCTOR
        ~vehData();

        //METHODS
        friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const vehData &v);

    private:
        typedef unsigned long longType;
        typedef std::size_t sizeType;
        sizeType used,capacity;
        vehReg *data;
    };
}
#endif
```

**vehData.cpp**

```
    //CONSTRUCTOR
    vehData::vehData(){
        capacity = 5;
        used = 0;
        data = new vehReg[capacity];
    }

    //DECONSTRUCTOR
    vehData::~vehData(){
        delete []data;
    }

    /* TRYING TO ACCOMPLISH THIS WITH AN OSTREAM OVERLOAD */
    void vehData::saveDataSloppy(){
        ofstream myFile;
        myFile.open ("database.db");
        for(int i=0;i<used;i++){
            myFile << data[i].getOwnerName() << "|";
            myFile << data[i].getVehicleLicense() << "|";
            myFile << data[i].getVehicleMake() << "|";
            myFile << data[i].getVehicleModel() << "|";
            myFile << data[i].getVehicleYear() << "\n";
        }
        myFile.close();
}

    void vehData::saveData(){
        cout << data;
    }

    ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, const vehData &v){
        stream << v.data;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a prime candidate for an [sscce](http://sscce.org). The answer of why it prints the address lies in the basics of pointers themselves, which I'm sure you learned if you have an assignment focused around them.

Comment: "it keeps printing the address of the pointer and not the data within" perhaps you could give us a clue as to what "it" refers to here? I've browsed through the (overly lengthy) code and not any possible suspect. As @chris suggests, cut it down to the simplest example you can produce that compiles, runs, and illustrates the problem. If that doesn't show you what's going wrong, post the cut down version of the code with a description of what you expect it to do and what it actually does.

Comment: @PeteBecker, It's the overloaded `operator<<` printing `v.data`, which is a pointer. I'd say [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/cce76ba541a348c700fd057e9e676595) is a good example of an sscce that replicates the problem you're having. Of course, as hinted in my first comment that the problem is with the pointers themselves, you wouldn't even need a structure for the problem to occur.

Comment: I am trying to print the contents of data (which is a pointer to a class which holds an array)

Comment: @chris - looks like you were willing to give it a more careful reading than I was.

Comment: By the way, your `vehData.cpp` has `namespace std;` in it, which, IIRC, has a use for one specific thing that I can't think of off the top of my head, but I don't think it's what you were going for.

Answer (score 2):

`v.data` is a pointer, so it prints a pointer.  How do you want it to
print whatever the pointer points to.  With the exception of character
pointers, the `<<` always prints what you give it (formatted in some
way).  If you don't want it to print a pointer, give is something else.

Suppose it did dereference the pointer.  What should it print: one
`vehReg`?  20?  A pointer has no information concerning the size.  If
you'd used `std::vector<vehReg>` (a much better choice), it would know
the size, but there's still no overload on `std::vector`, since the
system still doesn't know how you want it formatted (comma separated?
each on a new line?).  And you've not told it how to print a `vehReg` 
either.

You apparently understand the idea of how to overload `<<`.  The first
thing you'll have to do is provide an overload for `vehReg` as well.
And both overloads must be defined in terms of existing overloads:
there's not one for `std::vector`, and the one for pointer doesn't do
what you want (and couldn't), so you'll have to loop in your `<<` for
`vehData` and output each element, with whatever separators you decide
on.  (If it's each element on its own line, then you can use `std::copy`
and an `ostream_iterator` for the loop, but this may be a bit in advance
of what you've learnt so far.)  And forward to the `<<` for `vehReg` for
each `vehReg`.

Comment: @TimHibbard, They're dynamic arrays that do the management for you and share a common interface with other containers.

Comment: I guess I can do the following to make it easier.  This is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @TimHibbard Then something's wrong.  You should definitely have learned vectors before learning `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @JamesKanze I've updated the code above to show what I am trying to do.  The code above works however I do not think that what the professor wants.

Answer (score 0):

`v.data` is a pointer so it's a memory address.

`*v.data` is what the pointer is pointing to (which in this case is an integer).

For example,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main () { 
int *ptr; 
int var = 5;
ptr = &var;
cout << ptr << endl;
cout << *ptr << endl;
system("pause");
}
```

First line will print out something like: `0043F930`

Second line will print out: `5`

This should print out the elements held in the data array.

```
void vehData::showStructure() const {
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity: i++) {
         cout << data[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```